# How to verify data before sending to firebase - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to verify if the data is successfully sent to Firebase, I have a Field increment value, which is in the user's list, and the field increases every time when the user submits an answer, But the problem, even if the answers are empty and If I tap the addAnswer button, the increment is taking place, I want the increment counter only to be updated if the answer is successfully submitted.

Increment Future method

```
Future answerCounter(BuildContext context, String userID,)async{
return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
  'answercounter': FieldValue.increment(1),
});
}
```

The code for adding answer and answercounter

```
answerAdder(BuildContext context,
  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshot, String QuesID) {
return showModalBottomSheet(
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: constantColors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(25), topLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Divider(
              indent: 110,
              endIndent: 110,
              thickness: 4,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Provider.of<PostFunctions>(context, listen: false)
                          .addAnswer(
                              context,
                              documentSnapshot.data.data()['question id'],
                              answerController.text,
                              titleController.text)
                          .whenComplete(() {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                            print('adding counter');
                       if(documentSnapshot.hasData){
                         return  Provider.of<PostFunctions>(context, listen: false)
                             .answerCounter(context, Provider.of<Authentication>(context,listen: false).getUserUid);
                       } else {
                         print('error');
                       }
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `documentSnapshot.hasData()` always returns true. The name can be a little confusing but `hasData()` only checks if the content is [not null](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#:%7E:text=note%20that%20snapshot.hasdata%20only%20returns%20true%20when%20the%20snapshot%20contains%20a%20non-null%20data%20value.). That's why it always updates the counter. If you change that part adding something like:

```
 if(snapshot.hasData() && snapshot.data.exists()) {}
```

or

```
if (snapshot.data?.exists ?? false) {}
```

Any of those should work and only update the counter when the data really contains a document.

Comment: your welcome! If it worked, please update us with new info so anybody with asimilar problem can see it.